# Where is the constructor getting/setting the default allocator?

Tags: c++, boost

In regards to the [boost::circular_buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/circular_buffer.html) class,

I'm able to instantiate a simple one as follows:

```
#include<boost/circular_buffer.hpp>
int main() {
  boost::circular_buffer<double> buffer;
}
```

The circular_buffer class is templatized with

```
template<typename T, typename Alloc>
class circular_buffer {
  ... 
  typedef Alloc allocator_type;
  ...
}
```

and I believe the constructor being called is

```
explicit circular_buffer(const allocator_type & = allocator_type()) noexcept;
```

What i don't understand is where `buffer` is getting its default allocator?  The documentation states that, if one isn't explicitly provided, the Default Alloc object is an `std::allocator<T>`, but I don't see where this is being set.  I'm not trying to change it, I'm just trying to understand the design of this class from a c++/software-engineering point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class receives the allocator type as a template argument:

```
template<typename T, typename Alloc> 
class circular_buffer {
```

and the constructor argument just default-constructs an instance of that type.

If you use `circular_buffer` without specifying the `Alloc` template argument it uses the default specified in the base template declaration:

```
template <class T, class Alloc = BOOST_CB_DEFAULT_ALLOCATOR(T)>
class circular_buffer;
```

This is hiding in the `circular_buffer_fwd.hpp` header. The macro evaluates to `std::allocator<T>` or equivalent if the platform doesn't have that.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that there was a `circular_buffer_fwd.hpp` header being included.  The docs don't mention it, but I see it now after looking directly in the header on my pc.

Answer (score 3):

The `circular_buffer_fwd.hpp` header takes care of setting the default allocator

```
template <class T, class Alloc = BOOST_CB_DEFAULT_ALLOCATOR(T)>
class circular_buffer;
```